# Determining if there are free slots in a drive bay remotely

Tags: windows-server-2008, hard-drive

I have a server in a rack at a data center I don't have access to, and I want to confirm that there are drive bays open before I order new hardware.

There are two specific machines I need to know the configuration of:

A HP DL380s with iLO installed and Wndows Server 2008 R2, and a HP DL380 with VMWare ESXi 5.5 installed. I know that from the specs and what I ordered there should be slots free. However, I'd like to confirm this remotely if possible. Is there any way to do this short of physical access to the data center?

Comment: What hardware vendor management tools, if any, are installed on the server?

Comment: Just the normal iLO and HP management tools. I should probably have noted, and I'll clarify, that one of the machines is a VMWare ESXi server.

Comment: I would think that either one of those would give you the information you're looking for.

Comment: iLO will tell you.  I don't know off the top of my head.  Been a while since I've been in iLO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easily viewed in the ILO3 and ILO4 interfaces. Click on the Disk Bay tab.

In addition, the HP Smart Storage Administrator or HP Array Configuration Utility can tell you this.

Comment: It's pretty easily viewed in iLO2 as well, if not really all that intuitively.

Comment: Ah, I see. It omits bays that are empty, rather than showing them as empty.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming HP hardware:

```
$ sudo ./hpssacli
(or sudo ./hpacucli) :
=> ctrl all show

Smart Array P410i in Slot 0 (Embedded)    (sn: 50014380147E66D0)

=> ctrl slot=0 enclosure all show detail

Smart Array P410i in Slot 0 (Embedded)

   Internal Drive Cage at Port 1I, Box 1, OK
      Power Supply Status: Not Redundant
      Serial Number:
      Drive Bays: 4
      Port: 1I
      Box: 1
      Location: Internal

   Physical Drives
      physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, SAS, 900.1 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, SAS, 900.1 GB, OK)


   Internal Drive Cage at Port 2I, Box 1, OK
      Power Supply Status: Not Redundant
      Serial Number:
      **Drive Bays: 4**
      Port: 2I
      Box: 1
      Location: Internal

   Physical Drives
      **None attached**
```

Notice on this server I have whole cage (four drives) with no disks in it.
So I can add add four more drives there.